# Compile ODL controller

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to follow [this](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Ping) example but I found one problem. I am trying to compile ODL controller but the files structure have changed compared to the previous versions and I don't know in what path I have to be to compile the controller.

I am following

> git clone https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/p/controller.git
>
> Check that the used Yang tools version is >= 0.5.8-SNAPSHOT.

But I have 0.8.0 (downloaded today in the same link).

And then I have to do this to compile the ODL controller:

> cd controller/opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight
>
> mvn clean install

But this path doesn exist on the version I have donwloaded.

¿In what directory I have to be to run the mvn clean install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ping example wiki is old and outdated. That was back when everything was in the controller project except for yangtools and before ODL was converted to use karaf.  So the controller/opendaylight/distribution/opendaylight directory is long gone. So if you want to create and run the ping example, you would create a karaf feature and run the karaf distro in the controller project. You can follow what is done with the toaster sample and its associated wiki which is pretty up-to-date: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step.

Answer (score 0):

just run 'mvn clean install' in the root dir (so, the "controller" dir).

also, to be safe, I'd delete your "repository" directory in your .m2
dir (usually, in ~/.m2/repository).

Finally, make sure your mvn .settings.xml file is correct. here's a
[link](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html?highlight=settings.xml) for that.